# Using string-array list length as an integer

Tags: java, android, random, arrays

I'm using a random number generator to select an item out of an Android string array.  Is there a way to set my integer as the length of the array without actually counting the number of items in the array?

Here's an example of the random number code I'm using:

```
private Random random = new Random();
private int n = random.nextInt(4);

private String randText;

public Object(Context contex)
{
String[] string = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.text);

randText = "Stuff to display " + string[n] +".";
}

public String getRandText
{
return randText
}
```

I would like to define the "4" above as the length of a specific array list.  Anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I would like to define the "4" above as the length of a specific array list.**

Perhaps this is what you're after:

```
String[] strs = { "str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5" };

// Select a random (valid) index of the array strs
Random rnd = new Random();
int index = rnd.nextInt(strs.length);

// Print the randomly selected string
System.out.println(strs[index]);
```

To access the actual array, you do the following:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] yourStrings = res.getStringArray(R.array.your_array);
```

(Then to get the number of elements in the array, you do `yourStrings.length`.)

---

Regarding your edit. Try this instead:

```
private Random random = new Random();
private int n; // Can't decide up here, since array is not declared / initialized

private String randText;

public YourObject(Context contex) {
    String[] string = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.text);
    n = random.nextInt(string.length);     // <--- Do it here instead.
    randText = "Stuff to display " + string[n] +".";
}

public String getRandText {
    return randText;
}
```

Comment: I'm talking specifically about Android here, so I have a string array in strings.xml that I'm accessing... I'm not declaring an array in my code, just accessing the Android resource-- so I'm looking for syntax to access that resource (a string-array in strings.xml).

Comment: Then it should be an ordinary Java array, and you should be able to get the number of elements using the `arrayName.length` as suggested in my answer.

Comment: That was my initial thought too, but when I tried it, Eclipse gave an error of "arrayName cannot be resolved to a variable."

Comment: How did you declare the variable? (You need to put `String[]` in front of it!)

Comment: I did use String[]...  It's inside a class though, wonder if that's the problem.  Hang on, will provide more of my code.

Comment: That appears to have worked!  Thank you very much!  (Tried to vote you up, but I don't have the rep, evidently).

Comment: I am even more of a newb on Stack Overflow than I am with java/android.  Thanks again.

Comment: Haha, ok. You need 15 rep to upvote answers. You'll have it soon enough :-) just ask a few more questions for instance :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
List myList = ...
int n = select.nextInt(myList.size());
```

Comment: I'm talking specifically about Android here, so I have a string array in strings.xml that I'm accessing... I'm not declaring an array-list in my code, just accessing the Android resource-- so I'm looking for syntax to access that resource.